# How to validate textbox not to accept emailids

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have one field `Company profile`: textbox

If the user enters any emailid in textbox,validation errormessage should display that user cant enter emailids in textbox.

I have tried the following code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");

string[] values = commentstxt.Text.Trim().Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    bool isValid = regex.IsMatch(values[i].ToString().Trim());
    if (isValid)
    {
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CropImage", "alert('you can not enter email id.');", true);
        //break;
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('you can not enter email id in company profile.');window.location='addlisting.aspx';</script>");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Server.Transfer("addlistingpost.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

If the user enters only `test@gmail.com`, it gives the validation message saying you cannot enter emailid in the textbox which is correct and stays in the `addlisting.aspx` page.

If the user enters say `hello..how are you`, it redirects to the addlistingpost.aspx which is also correct.

The issue comes when user enters say `hello test@gmail.com how are you`, it does not throw a validation message as emailid is present in the textbox. I know here that it is only comparing `values[0]` which is `hello` and then directly goes into the else part.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What is an "emailids"?

Comment: Also, the regex you're using doesn't match the RFC 5322 spec for legal email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scan all the array till any error found. Kind of

```
Regex regex = new Regex(    @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
string[] values = commentstxt.Text.Trim().Split(' ');
bool isValid = true; // valid word == not email
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length && isValid; i++)
{
    bool isValid = !regex.IsMatch(values[i].ToString().Trim());
    if (!isValid)
    {
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CropImage", "alert('you can not enter email id.');", true);

        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('you can not enter email id in company profile.');window.location='addlisting.aspx';</script>");

    }
}
if (isValid)
{
    Server.Transfer("addlistingpost.aspx", true);
}
```

Comment: hi @Serg...Is it possible that i can use logical or part in Regex so that it also doesn't accept web address i.e. www.

Answer (score 2):

The Regex that you're using is matching the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string.

```
^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Just remove those characters to match anywhere within the line.

```
([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)
```

Try this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)");
string text = "hello test@gmail.com how are you";
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(text));
```

It outputs `True`.

Here's a regex, by the way, that nearly matches the RFC 5322 spec:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
        string[] values = commentstxt.Text.Trim().Split(' ');

        bool isValid = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {

            isValid = regex.IsMatch(values[i].ToString().Trim());


            if (isValid)
            {
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CropImage", "alert('you can not enter email id.');", true);
                //break;
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('you can not enter email id in company profile.');window.location='addlisting.aspx';</script>");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;

            }


        }

        if(!isValid)
        {
            Server.Transfer("addlistingpost.aspx", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like this and see if that would work ? :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
    string[] values = commentstxt.Text.Trim().Split(' ');
    bool hasEmail = false;
    foreach (string str in values)
    {
        bool isCurrentValid = regex.IsMatch(str.Trim());
        if (!isValid)
        {
            hasEmail = false;
        } else {
            hasEmail = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(hasEmail) {
        Server.Transfer("addlistingpost.aspx", true);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('you can not enter email id in company profile.');window.location='addlisting.aspx';</script>");
    }
```

I basically left the logic of checking the whole string out of the loop.